# Show data in datagridview filtered by current date C#

Tags: c#, mysql, performance, datagridview, datatable

i have large number of rows in my database. when i tried to load all the data in to datagridview it getting stuck. i want to load data to datagridview that only related datetimepicker date. this is my current code

```
private void showdatagrid()
{
    string constring = string.Format("datasource='{0}';username=uwadminview;port=3306;password=*****************;Connect Timeout=20000;Command Timeout=28800", dbserverip.Text);
    MySqlConnection conwaqDatabase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand cmdwaqDatabase = new MySqlCommand(" select * from waq115.loans ; ", conwaqDatabase);

    try
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmdwaqDatabase;
        dbdataset = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dbdataset);
        BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();
        bsource.DataSource = dbdataset;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bsource;
        sda.Update(dbdataset);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
        conwaqDatabase.Close();
    }
```

then soon after i call this i again use a rowfilter event like this

```
private void filterdata()
{
    DataView DV = new DataView(dbdataset);
    DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Convert(submittimestamp, System.String) LIKE '%{0}%'", adminviewDTP.Text);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DV;
}
```

but in this method performance is very bad when loading more than 9000 rows it getting stuck all the time. i want to method that directly query data from database only related  to today

(users are daily update the database and they are insert more than 500 rows each day)
(application still in a testing progress)
(i'm using mysql database)

can someone show me any efficient way to do this)

Comment: `Charith` why do you feel the need to use a BindingSource` just curious ...when all you need to do is assign the DataSource of the GridView to the dataset.. also 9000 rows is actually nothing and should load extremely fast.. can you add a `Where` clause or Filter at the Database end..?

Comment: sir i don't have good knowledge in C#. could you please show me how can i do it. i made this code using tutorial video :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MySqlCommand cmdwaqDatabase = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM waq115.loans WHERE DATE(submittimestamp) = DATE(NOW())", conwaqDatabase);
```

UPDATE:
With parameter:

```
MySqlCommand cmdwaqDatabase = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM waq115.loans WHERE DATE(submittimestamp) = DATE(@p)", conwaqDatabase);
```

then you can add the parameter like below

```
cmdwaqDatabase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P", dateTimeValue); // convert datetime picker value to DateTime and set as the value;
```

or

```
cmdwaqDatabase.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@P", MySqlDbType.Timestamp)).Value = dateTimeValue;
```

Comment: but when i add parameter like cam said it giving me this error   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: Ok, can you give sample value you get as adminviewDTP.Text? or what is the date time format you have used for datetimepicker ?

Comment: datetimepicker format is SHORT like this  mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: then try `DateTime dateTimeValue = DateTime.ParseExact(adminviewDTP.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: i edit my code as you said but after that my application wont open :S

Comment: `cmdwaqDatabase.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@P", MySqlDbType.Timestamp)).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;`

Answer (score 0):

Filter in the database tier instead of the middle tier.

```
    MySqlConnection conwaqDatabase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand cmdwaqDatabase = 
         new MySqlCommand("select * from waq115.loans where submittimestamp = @date; ", conwaqDatabase);


    var dateParam = new MySqlParameter();
    dateParam.Name = "@date";
    dateParam.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(adminviewDTP.Text);
    cmdwaqDatabase.Parameters.Add(dateParam);
```

Comment: thanks sir. but it giving me a error like this  Error 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments